# Variable in curl adds backslashes to string

Tags: shell-script, json, jq

I am trying to use curl based on some variables to create customers in Stripe, but when I assign the token to a variable it is giving me an error on Stripe saying that it does not exist. However, if I put the text in directly it works. How can I use the `$TOKEN` variable, is there something changing the value that I don't realize?

```
Michael$ curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers -u $access_token: -d source=tok_1CjvRiDZ5DqZ0yaUVWXXXXXX
{
  "error": {
    "code": "token_already_used",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/token-already-used",
    "message": "You cannot use a Stripe token more than once: tok_1CjvRiDZ5DqZ0yaUVWXXXXXX.",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}

Michael$ curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers -u $access_token: -d source=$TOKEN
{
  "error": {
    "code": "resource_missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",
    "message": "No such token: \"tok_1CjvRiDZ5DqZ0yaUVWXXXXXX\"",
    "param": "source",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

`$TOKEN` is assigned like this

```
OUTPUT="$(curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens -u $access_token: -d customer=$external_customer_id)"
TOKEN="$(echo $OUTPUT | jq .id)"
```

Comment: How do you assign the token to the variable. Any double quotes should not be part of the value (which they would be if you escape them).

Comment: I assign the token from a curl call, I will add the details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jq` gives the output quoted, as would be appropriate for JSON.

```
$ echo '{ "foo": "foobar" }' | jq .foo
"foobar"
```

The quotes end up as part of the contents of `TOKEN`, and are not removed when the variable is expanded. (They're just ordinary characters at that point.)

However, there's an option just for this:

> `--raw-output` / `-r`:
>
> With  this  option, if the filter´s result is a string then
>          it will be written directly to standard output rather than
>          being formatted as a JSON string with quotes. This can be
>          useful for making jq filters talk to non-JSON-based systems.

So, use `TOKEN="$(echo "$OUTPUT" | jq -r .id)"` instead.